# possible to import javax.comm on Android? want to open serial device

Tags: java, android, serial-port, javax.comm

I have a rooted Android device with a USB serial device connected.  The device shows up as "/dev/ttyUSB5"

I would like to open the serial port and read/write from it.  First and foremost... within Android, will it even allow me to read/open /dev/ttyUSB5?  Or within the application will I be prohibited from touching /dev ?  If I cannot touch anything in /dev, then this is all irrelevant.

However, if I can, then I am wondering if it is possible to import javax.comm so that I can communicate with the serial device.

As of right now, I am able to get around this by spawning a native C application which opens the serial port, then I use a socket to read/write to the serial port in Java.  However, it would be much better to do it all in Java.

Answer (score 3):

> within Android, will it even allow me to read/open /dev/ttyUSB5? Or within the application will I be prohibited from touching /dev ?

I am unsure if an ordinary SDK application will have rights to this. An application running as root would, if you have a rooted device.

> However, if I can, then I am wondering if it is possible to import javax.comm so that I can communicate with the serial device.

Not directly. The build tools don't want you importing `java.*` and `javax.*` classes. And, I don't know how quickly `javax.comm` drops down into native code, even on standard Java.

What you can try is see if Apache Harmony has an implementation of `javax.comm`, and take a look at it. If it seems like it will fit your needs, you can copy the relevant classes, then refactor them into a new package (e.g., `org.gynchis.comm`).

However, the *best* overall answer, if possible, is to try to stick with [the ADK and the new USB classes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html) added in API Level 10. I'm not a hardware guy, so I have no idea if what's in there will meet your needs, or if you have a device that is on a new enough Android version to have that support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the /dev/tty* to access your serial port.  Check this out :
[serialport-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/).  I tested it but of course, you need to have your /dev/tty* with the proper rights set. This is in the init.rc file (chmod 0666 /dev/ttyUSB5). If you are working in an embedded system, it's easy to fix. If you want to work on an "off the shelf any tablet on the market", it's more complicated. I believe the only way is to root it. The only drawback of that package is it seems to use a thread that constantly poll the inputstream which makes me believe it is not very CPU/battery efficient. I'm looking for a way to just get something that would wakeup my thread when data is available on the reception side.